# How to rotate few images in different angles using Javascript

Tags: image, image-manipulation, javascript, javascript-framework, styling

I need to take a list of images (Taken from the DB) and display them on my homepage
in a way that each image is rotated in another angle (finaly it will create half circle)

How can I write it in Javascript and control each the images angles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg) or [canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) for this...

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with these techniques.. I read somewhere that Canvas is not supported on IE6 & 7 so it might be a problem..